# Forcing admin credentials to force change of System Locale from US to UK

Tags: powershell

The script now looks like this:

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))

{   
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
Break
}
Set-WinSystemLocale en-gb
Set-WinHomeLocation 0xF2
Set-Culture en-gb
```

Where in there can I set it so it automatically enters my username and password to bypass the credentials box as I am wanting this script to run automatically whilst the build is running.

Can you help?

Comment: If you believe it needs admin creds, why don't you just run as admin? `Win+X -> A` in Win10.

Comment: We need it to work using the script as we are to include this in the build.

Comment: Please see my edit of the post as the script is now updated.

Comment: ["Note that because this is a system setting, this can only be changed by a user with Administrator permissions, and changes do not take effect until the computer is restarted."](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh852118). This is, frankly, an insane thing to do in a build script. If you really need this, and you can't change the settings yourself once and be done with it, set up a virtual machine with the correct configuration that the build can run on.

Comment: Why bother with the if statement?  Be 100% sure and just start the process as admin.